# I cannot convert xacro file to urdf

Tags: ros-kinetic, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have an issue about broadcasting some links at tf for which I have asked [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/250764/tf-tree-doesnt-show-broadcasted-joints/). Someone commented that he solved my issue from converting the xacro file to a urdf one. How can I do that?

I have searched for the issue in questions like [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/10401/how-to-convert-xacro-file-to-urdf-file/) and [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2818/please-help-how-to-open-urdfxacro-file-in-gazebo/) and when I type:

```
rosrun xacro xacro.py rover_ws/src/labrob/labrob_description/urdf/labrob.urdf
```

or

```
rosrun xacro xacro.py 'rover_ws/src/labrob/labrob_description/urdf/labrob.urdf'
```

I get an error like the following:

```
xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
No such file or directory: rover_ws/src/labrob/labrob_description/urdf/labrob.urdf
XacroException('No such file or directory: rover_ws/src/labrob/labrob_description/urdf/labrob.urdf',)
```

The directory is the correct one I am writting here, I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Could you please help me?

Thanks for your answers and time in advance,

Chris

PS: I am in ROS Kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251063/i-cannot-convert-xacro-file-to-urdf/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2017-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

did you try it with an absolute path?

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2017-01-01**:
Thank you the command worked with the absolute path...if you would like add this as an answer to accept it...Your suggestion at my other question didn't work though with the converted urdf...I still get a wrong tree.